# How to use substr on MySQL update record?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have been trying to update records but can't seem to code in the substr command to extract certain details from a string.

I have a "doa" (date of accident) text field currently working with kelvinluck's jquery datepicker plugin.

Originally the single doa textfield was split into three drop downs, namely: doaDay, doaMonth, doaYear. Each had their own field in the database as well.

But I've decided to unify the doaDay, doaMonth, doaYear into one single field, called doa and us kevinluck's jquery datepicker plugin.

Now as I have well over a 100 records in my database using the doaDay, doaMonth, doaYear fields I decided to use the substr command in order to extract the dd (doaDay), mm (doaMonth) and yyyy (doaYear) from the new updated dd/mm/yyyy (field).

This was my solution when INSERTING the database:

```
$doa = $_POST['doa'];
$doaDay = substr($doa, 0, 2);
$doaMonth = substr($doa, 4, 5);
$doaYear = substr($doa, 7, 10);
```

Then the record was inserted after POST.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_personalinjury (`doaDay`, `doaMonth`, `doaYear`)                          
VALUES ('$doaDay', '$doaMonth', '$doaYear')");
```

Now the problem arises when im trying to update the record. As a completely new method is used and I am having difficulty implementing it. Here is what I have so far.

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE tbl_accident SET doaDay=%s, doaMonth=%s, doaYear=%s, WHERE id=$client_id",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['doaDay'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['doaMonth'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['doaYr'], "text"),
```

How do I go about extracting dd, mm, yyyy from the doa textfield and assigning the values to $doaDay, $doaMonth, and $doaYear respectively?

Comment: Why are you splitting out the day, month and year rather than store it as a DATETIME?!  You'd use the MySQL STR_TO_DATE(string, 'date_format') for both insert & update...

Comment: thanks for the reply. i started building the program as a novice so i have inconvenienced myself in many ways. despite learning new things each day and better ways of working i find myself having to tweak the fruit of these new lessons slightly (dumb them down) to accommodate the current system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do `$doa_bits = explode('/', $doa);` .  This should give you an array with 3 items, `$doa_bits[0]` would be the day, `$doa_bits[1]` would be the month and `$doa_bits[2]` would be the year.

Comment: how would this fit in the context of the second example? "if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form")) {..."

Comment: i have posted the edited code below as a seperate answer as im not sure how to use the formatting within this box.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form")) {
$doa_bits = explode('/', $doa)
      $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE tbl_accident SET doaDay=%s, doaMonth=%s, doaYear=%s, WHERE id=$client_id",
                           GetSQLValueString($doa_bits[0], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($doa_bits[1], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($doa_bits[2], "text"),
```

is this what you are alluding to good sir?